# Infix to Postfix Output program

Tags: c++, string, stack, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I am a novice C++ programmer. I have written the following C++ code for infix to postfix expressing using an array-based stack, however, I get `^2` in string each time and also I can't figure out why my answer is not correct.

I can't find the logical error either. Can someone please help me with this?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using std::string;

class stack {
public:
    int top;
    char* astack;
    int size;
    stack(int s) {
        size = s;
        top = -1;
        astack = new char[size];
    }
    void Push(char element);
    char Pop();
    bool isEmpty();
    bool isFull();
    char Peek();
    void clear();
    void print(stack* ptr);
};

char stack::Peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    return astack[top];
}

void stack::clear() {
    top = -1;
    delete astack;
    astack = new char(size);
};

void stack::Push(char element) {
    if (isFull()) {
        cout << "The stack is already Full" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else
        astack[++top] = element;
    return;
}

char stack::Pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "The Array is already empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        return astack[--top];
    }
}

void stack::print(stack* ptr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ptr->top; i++) {
        cout << ptr->astack[i];
    }
}

bool stack::isEmpty() {
    if (top == -1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

bool stack::isFull() {
    if (top == size - 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int precedence(char element) {
    int weight = -1;
    switch (element) {
    case '+':
    case '-':
        weight = 1;
    case '*':
    case '/':
        weight = 2;
    case '$':
        weight = 3;
    }
    return weight;
}

bool IsOperator(char C) {
    if (C == '+' || C == '-' || C == '*' || C == '/' || C == '$')
        return true;
    return false;
}

bool IsOperand(char C) {
    if (C >= '0' && C <= '9') return true;
    if (C >= 'a' && C <= 'z') return true;
    if (C >= 'A' && C <= 'Z') return true;
    return false;
}

int main() {
    string infix;
    getline(cin, infix);

    int j = 1;

    string post = "";

    stack* postfix = new stack(50);
    for (int i = 0; i != infix.size(); i++) {
        char element = infix[i];
        if (IsOperand(element)) {
            post += element;
        }
        if (IsOperator(element)) {
            if (precedence(element) >precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
                postfix->Push(element);
            }
            else {
                while (precedence(element) <= precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
                    if (precedence(element) < precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
                        post += postfix->Pop();
                    }
                    if (precedence(element) == precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
                        cout << postfix->Peek() << endl;
                        post += postfix->Pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    while (!postfix->isEmpty()) {
        post += postfix->Pop();
    }

    cout <<"Postfix expression is : "<< post;
}
```

The output is attached below:

[image]

Expected output: `576/1*-6+`

I can't figure out why it has `^2` in output instead of operator symbols and also the answer is different. Please help me with this.

Comment: Did you debugging already? I would start to check what appears in `while (!postfix->isEmpty()) {
        post += postfix->Pop();
    }` and then "fight" backwards.

Comment: I [**compiled your code on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a2a2a1cd20d6328c). Please, note the last warning. This is Undefined Behavior. (You may think - Pah. This isn't even reached in my tests. But this is only half of the truth. If a code with Undefined Behavior is included then the compiler is free to compile it to any non-sense, and it may "optimize" it to compile the whole code to any non-sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting off, I just want to point out that the use of classes is for data hiding. Making your `top`, `size`, and other data members of `public` scope completely defeats the purpose.
Secondly, the nomenclature of classes should start with an uppercase alphabet.

The first error is with your `stack::Push(char)` method. Note the difference between `return astack[--top]` and `return astack[top--]`. The former decreases the value of `top` by 1, and then returns the value, whereas, the latter returns the value of `astack[top]` and then decrements `top`.

This is very crucial as what you really want is to return the value popped, and not the value at the top of the stack after popping.

```cpp
char stack::Pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        cout << "The Array is already empty" << endl;
    }
    else {
        // Note the change here.
        return astack[top--];
    }
}
```

Furthermore, since `stack::print(stack *)` is a method of the class, every instance has its own copy for this member function. There is no need to explicitly pass an instance of `stack` to it. You can achieve this by the following piece of code:

```cpp
void stack::print() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= top; ++i) {
        cout << astack[i];
    }
    
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Coming over to your `precedence(char)` function, you need to break out of a switch condition when your goal is achieved.

```cpp
int precedence(char element) {
    switch (element) {
        
        case '+': return 1;
        case '-': return 1;
        case '*': return 2;
        case '/': return 2;
        case '$': return 3;
        
        default: return -1;
    }
}
```

Moving onto your algorithm of converting infix to postfix, you have to keep popping all same or higher priority operators from the stack, and then push your scanned operator.

```cpp
if (IsOperand(element)) {
    post += element;
}
else if (IsOperator(element)) {
    if (precedence(element) > precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
        postfix->Push(element);
    }
    else {
        while (precedence(element) <= precedence(postfix->Peek())) {
            post += postfix->Pop();
        }
        
        postfix->Push(element);
    }
}
```

I would suggest a few more changes such as adding to check for parantheses, but that seems to be out of the scope of this question. Good luck!

Comment: THANK YOU so much!!!!, its perfectly working now and i have added the case of parenthesis as well , all working now !